# Expanding the range into a list of consecutive numbers in a table in R

Tags: r

Here is in example of my table with columns ID, A and B:

```
ID    A        B
5     1        758
5     1        560
50    500      8156
```

I would like to convert this into a list of consecutive numbers (increasing 1+) in a table with the same ID. Here is an example of the table I would like:

```
ID   Position
5    1, 2, 3 ... 758
50   500, 501, 502 ... 8156
```

I've attempted this on a table in R with seq(...) and I have used the colon function, however I receive the same warning message, as follows:

Warning messages:
1: In x6$S1:x6$E1 :
  numerical expression has 281 elements: only the first used

Does anyone know a way around this? I have been able to do it with arrays in perl, but I was unable to keep the IDs.

Cheers,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` you could do:

```
library("dplyr")
DF
#  ID   A    B
#1  5   1  758
#2  5   1  560
#3 50 500 8156


summaryDF = DF %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        summarise(minPos = min(A),maxPos = max(B)) %>%
        as.data.frame()

summaryDF
#  ID minPos maxPos
#1  5      1    758
#2 50    500   8156

#you can modify step here, have chosen large step for ease in output
step = 750      

#For each ID, we create a seq from minPos to maxPos and using paste0 
#to collapse into one string

customFun = function(x) {

data.frame(ID=x$ID,minPos=x$minPos,maxPos=x$maxPos,Position=paste0(seq(x$minPos,x$maxPos,step),collapse=","),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

}

summaryDF = summaryDF %>% 
            group_by(ID) %>% 
            do(customFun(.)) %>% 
            as.data.frame()
```

**Output:**

```
summaryDF
#  ID minPos maxPos                                              Position
#1  5      1    758                                                 1,751
#2 50    500   8156 500,1250,2000,2750,3500,4250,5000,5750,6500,7250,8000
```